# Initialize Public class via private category

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I am building an SDK, and I have a class that I want to be public to the users, but I do not want them creating this object themselves. The method I came up with to solve this is by having a private category on the object and doing my initialization of this object in the category. Additionally the properties in the public header are readonly because I also don't want the users modifying the objects they receive. What I have in the category .h looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *property;

- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

And the .m looks like this:

```
@implementation MyObject (Category)

- (instanceType)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Object created");
        [object setProperty:data[@"property"];
        NSLog(@"Property set");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setProperty:(NSString *)property {
    self.property = property;
}
```

This code prints the "object created" statement, but not the "property set" statement. The UI of my app then locks up and there is no error or crash returned. So my question is, how do I get these properties to be set for this custom object?

Comment: OK, what's your question? Please edit your "question" so it actually asks a question.

Comment: sorry stopped mid thought, but its up

Comment: Welcome to infinite recursion followed by a stack overflow.

Comment: so you're saying it is just setting the property a bunch via the setProperty method, which causes the overflow? How do I avoid this and just get the property set once, but not in the main class?

Comment: Don't implement the `setProperty:` method. There's no reason give the code you posted.

Comment: Couldn't you expose the public interface as a `protocol` instead?

Comment: I'm really trying to copy other sdks, which have objects exposed, but the properties are readonly and there are no init methods publicly available